# How to remove include file TODO's from VS itself from the task list?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, todo

Suddenly I get like 10 TODO's in my task list in Visual Studio 2022, which are inside the folder

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\...
```

I'm doing a C++ Console project.

The strange thing is that these TODO's didn't pop up yesterday (and not even closed Visual Studio).

What I tried:

- Reopening project
- Restarting VS.
- Removing the TODO from the Tools/Options menu, Environment/Task List tab, but the TODO token cannot be deleted.

I could overwrite the C++ VS include files by removing the TODO's in the source, but that seems like a strange hack.

How can I get rid of these unnecessary TODO's in the task list?

Below is a screen of the TODO's.. only the last 8 are mine (which are not in C:\Program Files (x86)...

***Update***

I found the reason.

I added the following include statement:

```
#include <Windows.h>
```

Because I want later to change (external) windows positions.
However, the question remains the same.

[image]

*** Update 2 ***

My Tools/Options, Task List setup window looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What is the content of the TODO's that are appearing in the task list? Are they related to your source code or the headers in the include folder? Can you try to create a new empty C++ console project and see if these TODO's still appear in the task list?

Comment: @KaramMohamed Good questions ... I found one include file that is added (Windows.h).